# Search all relationships/Nodes in the path and Filter by a property list Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 questions.

1) How to search all the relationships and filter on property list for PID (ProductID).

2) How to search all the nodes in the Path and filter on property list for PID (ProductID)

[Here is what the graph look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs6kY.png)

Below query filter the path successfully but I have hard coded the List index to 0

```
 match path= (n1) -[rel*..10] ->(n2) 
where all(rel in relationships(path)where rel.PID[0]=2)
return path
```

1) How to search the all the relationships and filter on list for a PID (ProductID)

I tried the below query replaced the hard coded index value PID[0] with the loop but it returns me nothing. Please help me understand whats wrong with the query.

```
match path= (n1) -[rel*..10] ->(n2) 
where all(rel in relationships(path)where [x in rel.PID  where x=2])
return rel
```

2) How to search the all the nodes in the Path and filter on list for PID (ProductID)

Similarly what will be the query for the nodes.

Below query runs successfully, but I have hard coded the List index to 0

```
match path= (n1:Product) -[rel*..10] ->(n2) 
where all(r in nodes(path)where  r.PID[0]=1)
return path
```

Replaced the hard coded index value PID[0] & it returns me nothing.

```
match path= (n1:Product) -[rel*..10] ->(n2) 
where all(r in nodes(path)where [x in  r.PID where x=1])
return nodes(path)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Cypher code for the Graph

```
    CREATE 
  (`0` :Supplier {name:"Supplier1"}) ,
  (`3` :Airport {name:"Johannesburg",city:"Johannesburg",country:"South Africa",PID:'[1,2]'}) ,
  (`5` :Warehouse {name:"WareHouse1",PID:'[1,2]'}) ,
  (`8` :Airport {name:"Dusseldorf",city:"Dusseldorf",PID:'[1]'}) ,
  (`9` :Airport {name:"Brisbane",city:"Brisbane",country:"Australia",PID:'[1]'}) ,
  (`10` :Airport {name:"Perth",city:"Perth",country:"Australia",PID:'[1,2]'}) ,
  (`11` :Product {name:"Product1",PID:'[2]'}) ,
  (`12` :Product {name:"Product 2",PID:'[2]'}) ,
  (`20` :Airport {name:"Frankfurt",city:"Germany",country:"Germany",PID:'[2]'}) ,
  (`9`)-[:`TRANSPORT` {PID:'[1]'}]->(`10`),
  (`20`)-[:`TRANSPORT` {PID:'[2]'}]->(`3`),
  (`3`)-[:`TRANSPORT` {PID:'[2]'}]->(`10`),
  (`5`)-[:`RECEIVES` ]->(`10`),
  (`12`)-[:`TRANSPORT` {PID:'[2]'}]->(`20`),
  (`0`)-[:`TRANSPORT` ]->(`12`),
  (`0`)-[:`TRANSPORT` ]->(`11`),
  (`11`)-[:`TRANSPORT` {PID:'[2]'}]->(`8`),
  (`8`)-[:`TRANSPORT` {PID:'[1]'}]->(`3`),
  (`3`)-[:`TRANSPORT` {PID:'[1]'}]->(`9`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Movie Graph sample database, I wrote the statement below which I think is roughly equivalent to what you're looking to do. The Movie Graph's :ACTED_IN relationships have the property `roles` which is a list of strings. The statement matches all of the actors who played a role called "Neo" in a movie. In this case it finds all three Matrix movies with Keanu Reeves as the actor. Hopefully this is some help.

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[ai:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH a AS actor, m AS movie, ai.roles AS roles
UNWIND roles AS role
WITH actor, movie, role
WHERE role = "Neo"
RETURN actor.name, movie.title, role
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the simpler way to do it. Replace 1 in the below query with the PID you are searching for.

1) How to search all the relationships and filter on property list for PID (ProductID).

```
match path= (n1) -[rel*..8] -(n2)<-[:RECEIVES]-(n3)
where   all(rel in relationships(path) where 1 in rel.PID)
return path
```

2) How to search all the nodes in the Path and filter on property list for PID (ProductID)

```
match path= (n1) -[rel*..8] -(n2)<-[:RECEIVES]-(n3)
where   all(rel in nodes(path) where 1 in rel.PID)
return path
```